# SSRS Report Manager set default zoom level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have deployed around 40 report parts to my reporting server which are all working correctly.

The problem is my zoom is default 100 for all of them, I want a number of them to default to 75.

I have tried creating a portal with links to all report parts and using the `&rc:Zoom=75`
on the end of the URL for the link but it still defaults to 100.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of going to :

```
http://mysqlservername/Reports/
```

and getting the full URL from here (plus `&rc:Zoom=75`)

I went here:

```
http://mysqlservername/ReportServer
```

Which is like the back end.

From here I went to the report part I wanted to default to 75 and right clicked and selected'copy shortcut'

I then pasted this into the 'Go to URL' box along with the

```
&rc:Zoom=75
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your full URL? I realized that the zoom doesn't work if I also have `&rc:toolbar=false`. If I add `&rc:Zoom=25` to a standard report it work's fine.

Try removing any other tags than you may have on the URL to see which one is preventing the Zoom from working.