# Font size differences when converting Crystal reports to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

When converting Crystal reports to SSRS reports I can specify the exact same font and size, but the resulting text is larger in SSRS (when viewing either on the web or as a PDF). I understand that each reporting tool has its own engine and may simply interpret the same information differently ([Social.MSDN: Same Font looks different in Crystal Report and SSRS report](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a657dbf-80a6-46e0-8ae0-220b82874e8b/same-font-looks-different-in-crystal-report-and-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices)).

**What is the best way to match font size when converting from Crystal reports to SSRS reports?** Is there a conversion formula (e.g., SSRS fonts should be 90% of Crystal report size) or setting in SSRS to change how fonts are interpreted (i.e., scale, not zoom)?

Additional info:
I am already aware that an overall zoom can be set for SSRS web viewing ([SSRS Report Manager set default zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848604/ssrs-report-manager-set-default-zoom-level)), but this reducing the entire page size (not just the elements on the page). I'm also aware that Crystal reporting can cause fonts to be smaller when exporting to PDF ([Font size is decreased when exporting Crystal Report to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212290/font-size-is-decreased-when-exporting-crystal-report-to-pdf)).

**Example:** web view of SSRS and Crystal reports (8pt Arial font)
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30773527/SSRSvCrystalExample.PNG

(I apologize I can't embed the image--I don't have enough reputation points yet)

Comment: How are you converting the reports to ssrs?

Comment: Mostly manually—opening the Crystal report in Crystal Viewer or Visual Studio and recreating the report in SSRS. With things like font size and the stored proc I can copy and paste directly across, but other visual elements are created again manually in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my SSRS fonts 1pt smaller than the Crystal reports. This isn't a perfect solution, although the size is very close the spacing is still slightly off.

**Example:** longer text to show spacing difference
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30773527/FontChangeSSRS.PNG